# Moving image from scrollView to View

Tags: iphone

I have created a `scrollview` and have added it to my view controller class. Now I have items in `scrollview`. On touch I want to move image to the main view. I am trying using `touchesBegin` and `touchesMoved` but it's not working. How can I do it?

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"touch moved");
    dummyDress.frame=CGRectMake(location.x, location.y , 80, 120);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle the touches in one of the UIScrollView's subviews, it would be best to read the Overview section in the [UIScrollView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html). See `touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContentView:`, `pagingEnabled`, and `delaysContentTouches`, among others.

Comment: hii ya i have tried bt not working i have an imageview where i want to drag and drop tht image from scroll view

Comment: yes i have enabled it bt the image is not moving byyond the scrollview i have an image view where i have to drag that image from scroll view plz help guys

Answer (score 0):

Have you set `userInteractionEnabled = YES` on the `UIImageView` instance?

`UIImageView`, and `UILabel` override the default value of `YES` from the `UIView` base implementation, and instead return `NO`.

Comment: yes i have enabled it bt the image is not moving byyond the scrollview i have an image view where i have to drag that image from scroll view plz help guy